# Improving IO performance on a mounted directory?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, bash, multiprocessing

I'm trying to optimize a Python test that involves writing some 100k files to a mounted directory using SSH & a simple Bash command.

I'm rather inexperienced at this so I need some advice on how to minimize IO time.

Basically the Python script mounts a directory on a remote server (let's call it `%MOUNTED_DIRECTORY%` for that matter), then SSH into the remote host and calls the following bash command on that host:

```sh
for number in `seq 1 100000`; do touch %MOUNTED_DIRECTORY%/test_file$number; done
```

I find that a lot of time on spent on this process, waiting for the creation of the files to finish. I need the files to be created before I continue, so I can't do anything in the meantime - I have to speed up the process.

Also, when the directory is mounted it takes a lot more time to finish than when it's not, so that's why I'm in this problem in the first place.

I thought about multithreading or multiprocessing but they don't seem to be efficient, either because I'm doing something wrong or because the command is actually on a remote host and is creating the files with Bash, not Python?

Comment: You can also tell touch to touch multiple files at once, thus dramatically reducing the processes that need to run.

Comment: Note that this might exceed some limits (command line length, number of arguments etc), so you will probably still need some chopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xargs:

```
seq 1 100000 | sed 's|^|%MOUNTED_DIRECTORY%/test_file|' | xargs touch
```

This passes as many names as possible to each touch command.